# Regex to remove spaces around parenthesis in Java

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

What I would like to do is change things like `printf ( ... );` to `printf(...);` with a regular expression. I've tried variations of `line = line.replaceAll("\\s([(])\\s", "(");`, but this isn't working. What expression should I be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
"\\s*\\(\\s*([^)]*?)\\s*\\)\\s*"
```

And replace with `($1)`. See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nC0hW8/1)

The point is that on both sides of `(` and `)` you can match whitespace with `\s*`, but in order to match the whitespace before the `)`, you need to use lazy matching since `[^)]` that matches any character but a `)` can also match whitespace.

Or, just match all whitespace around any `()`:

```
"\\s*([()])\\s*"
```

And replace with `$1`.

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/nC0hW8/2)

Answer (score 0):

If your strings may contain spaces around parentheses then you should consider parsing the Java rather than doing this with regex. This project has a Java parser which looks usable:

https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser